# Weird part of DateTime.parse(data['datetime']) in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

#### Problem Description

I have `020-03-20T14:16:27.189282+08:00` return from my database and I am trying to convert it to `2:16pm` using DateTime.parse(). However,every time I convert the time, I get `6:16am`.

#### Question

May I know how could I solve this problem?

#### MyCode

```
dateTime = `020-03-20T14:16:27.189282+08:00`
time = DateFormat.jm().format(DateTime.parse(dateTime));
print(time);
```

Comment: You're getting `6:16am` because the value you're using contains a UTC offset `+08:00`, btw.

Comment: Arr, I see. Another word, for me to get 2.16pm. I need to get rid of the offset +08:00. Noted.

Answer (score 2):

Dai, thanks for your small tips.

Solutions for this question is remove the offset from the string.

#### Why

The result is always in either local time or UTC. `If a time zone offset other than UTC is specified, the time is converted to the equivalent UTC time`.

Read it here https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/DateTime/parse.html.

#### Answered

```
String dateTime = `020-03-20T14:16:27.189282+08:00`;
int indexOfPlusMinusSymbol = dateTime .indexOf('+') >= 0
          ?dateTime .lastIndexOf('+')
          : dateTime .lastIndexOf('-');
String time = DateFormat.jm().format(DateTime.parse(dateTime..substring(0, indexOfPlusMinusSymbol)));
print(time);
```